# Php missing extension for php_intl via composer install

Tags: php, extensions, magento2.2, centos

The OS version is CentOS 6.6. I have installed PHP 7.1.4 and all PHP extensions are installed except for intl.

I did the following commands:

```
yum list php*intl
```

And installed the one that was compatible with my PHP version

```
yum install php71-php-intl.x86_64
```

Despite that, intl doesn't appear when I do 'php -m' and I still get the error in composer :

```
magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 requires ext-intl * ->
```

Is there a way to install the intl? I have restarted the apache server several times but no luck. What do you think i'm missing?

Comment: yum --enablerepo=remi install php-intl

Comment: @andyjones - It didn't work because it installs php 5 instead of 7.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by removing the PHP via yum remove php and re-install PHP by following the link here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html

I used the commands for PHP 7 on CentOS. Had to downgrade php from 7.1.4 to 7.0.26. This is also fine as this version is compatible with Magento 2.2